# ImportError: No module named locallibrary.settings

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

You could have seen the question so many times.

But unluckily I cant solve this error.

I am using python 2.7.12 , django 1.8

The tutorial source I learn is Mozilla django development where they teach with latest version of python3 and django 1.10

Somehow I tackled to use with older version.

everything was going good until I started to import models to admin.

soem class codes started showing that it has no object member, even though it exist

and hence I finally got the error as

```
"ImportError: No module named locallibrary.settings"
```

Here what I tried:

Updated to python 3(thought that could be the problem)

appended correct sys path() with project path.

Still same error showing up

Anybody help me out for solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to import the settings of your project, try importing

```
from django.conf import settings
```